# Convert datetime column to utc time

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to achieve the following.

I have a datetime column that i calculated with the following functions.

```
to_char(to_date(f_sta_date, 'YYYYMMDD') + (f_sta_time)/86400), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
to_char(to_date(f_sta_date, 'YYYYMMDD') + (f_sta_time)/86400), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

T1

```
f_sta_date f__sta_time f_sto_date  f_sto_time DT_sta              DT_sto
20191001   6689        20191001    7185       2019-10-01 01:54:49 2019-10-01 01:59:45
```

Desired table

T1

```
f_sta_date f_sta_time_id f_sto_date f_sto_time_id DT_sta              DT_sto               DT_sta_UTC  DT_sto_UTC
20191001   6689          20191001   7185          2019-10-01 01:54:49 2019-10-01 01:59:45
```

What function could i add to the `functions` above to achieve the desired result?

Comment: Something doesn't make sense. You want the output as "UTC time" - which means a specific time zone. But your input is just a date-time without time zone information. Are you **assuming** that the inputs are in fact meant as UTC date and time? Or are they assumed to be in some other time zone (perhaps the database server time zone? or something else?) and you also need to convert from that time zone to UTC? Either way, you need to clarify.

Comment: The input time (f_sta_time_id) is a key from a dimension table, where the time is stored in local time

Comment: "Local" to what? The process that inserts or updates data on a table is always run from a "client" - "local" time may mean "local to the client process". On the other hand, "local" may also mean "local to the database server". For example, my database server may be in New York, but my client (my computer, from which I connect to the database) is in Los Angeles. Both the database "local" time and the client "local" time can be accessed, with different Oracle functions. So, what does "local" mean in your problem? Local to what/whom?

Comment: The time stored in the dimension table is in CET

Answer (score 0):

To start with: `to_char()` returns a string from a date. So if you want a `date`, don't use it, ie replace this:

```
to_char(to_date(f_sta_date, 'YYYYMMDD') + (f_sta_time)/86400), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

To:

```
to_date(f_sta_date, 'YYYYMMDD') + f_sta_time/86400
```

Then: when it comes to managing timezones, you need to use the `timestamp with time zone` datatype instead of `date`. To convert your date in localtime (ie the time zone of your session, that is defined by `SESSIONTIMEZONE`) to a timestamp and get the corresponding date/time at UTC, you can do:

```
cast(to_date(f_sta_date, 'YYYYMMDD') + f_sta_time/86400 as timestamp with time zone) 
    at time zone 'UTC'
```

Your query:

```
select
    to_date(f_sta_date, 'YYYYMMDD') + f_sta_time/86400 dt_sta,
    to_date(f_sto_date, 'YYYYMMDD') + f_sto_time/86400 dt_sto,
    cast(to_date(f_sta_date, 'YYYYMMDD') + f_sta_time/86400 as timestamp) 
        at time zone 'UTC' dt_sta_utc,
    cast(to_date(f_sto_date, 'YYYYMMDD') + f_sto_time/86400 as timestamp) 
        at time zone 'UTC' dt_sto_utc
from t
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the comment.

Is there a function to trim it from 30-NOV-19 12.54.49.000000000 AM UTC to

30:NOV-19 12:54:49

Comment: This **assumes** that the inputs were meant to be in UTC time zone. Perhaps this assumption is correct, but it should be stated explicitly.

Comment: THe input time is local time

Comment: The function you are looking for is TO_CHAR. See [Doumentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/functions165.htm) and [Date Time Format Models](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/sql_elements004.htm#i34510).

Comment: When you use `{TIMESTAMP} AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'` then `timestamp` is considered in current `SESSIONTIMEZONE` - this might be wrong or correct.

Answer (score 0):

From the discussion in comments under your post, it appears that your date-time (which you are already able to calculate) should instead be a timestamp **with time zone**, specifically "at time zone CET". Perhaps for your purposes **date** with time zone would suffice (in Oracle, "date" always means date-time); alas, Oracle doesn't have such a data type, we must use **timestamp** with time zone.

Below I show how to calculate that, in the `WITH` clause. (Note that I use a different approach for computing even the date-time - I convert your "time" component to seconds directly, using the Oracle function specifically designed for that, instead of arithmetic operations. Also, while Oracle usually allows you to use a number - your *date* component - as if it were a string, in some cases it doesn't. For example, you can do that in `TO_DATE`, but you can't in `TO_TIMESTAMP`. In any case, you should **never** rely on such implicit conversions; always make them explicit in your code.)

I show how I created the table for testing; then, in the query, in the `WITH` clause I do a preliminary computation (computing your `DT_STA` and `DT_STO`, but as timestamps **with time zone**); then in the main query I show how to convert to a different time zone.

```
create table t1 (
  f_sta_date number, 
  f_sta_time number,
  f_sto_date number,
  f_sto_time number
);
insert into t1 values (20191001, 6689, 20191001, 7185);
commit;

with
  prep (f_sta_date, f_sta_time, f_sto_date, f_sto_time, dt_sta, dt_sto) as (
    select f_sta_date, f_sta_time, f_sto_date, f_sto_time,
           from_tz(to_timestamp(to_char(f_sta_date), 'yyyymmdd') 
                   + numtodsinterval(f_sta_time, 'second'), 'CET'),
           from_tz(to_timestamp(to_char(f_sto_date), 'yyyymmdd')
                   + numtodsinterval(f_sto_time, 'second'), 'CET')
    from   t1       
  )
select f_sta_date, f_sta_time, f_sto_date, f_sto_time, dt_sta, dt_sto,
       dt_sta at time zone 'UTC' as dt_sta_utc,
       dt_sto at time zone 'UTC' as dt_sto_utc
from   prep
;

F_STA_DATE F_STA_TIME F_STO_DATE F_STO_TIME DT_STA                  DT_STO                  DT_STA_UTC              DT_STO_UTC             
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------------------- ----------------------- ----------------------- -----------------------
  20191001       6689   20191001       7185 2019-10-01 01:51:29 CET 2019-10-01 01:59:45 CET 2019-09-30 23:51:29 UTC 2019-09-30 23:59:45 UTC
```

Comment: You are right, `CET` considers daylight saving times, forget my comment.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the comment

Is there a function to trim it from 30-NOV-19 12.54.49.000000000 AM UTC to 30:NOV-19 12:54:49?